# summing up the values of a column in django framework

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in my django web app and I have been trying to query the model in such a way that I can sum up values in the quantity column. I already have data in this model so I just need to add up all the values in the quantity column.

```
class ProductInstance(models.Model):
product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.RESTRICT,related_name='product')
quantity=models.IntegerField()
warehouse=models.ForeignKey(Warehouse,on_delete=models.RESTRICT,related_name='warehouse')
```

I tried "ProductInstance.objects.sum(quantity)". It didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregate functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/) for this kind of cases.

```
from django.models import Sum
ProductInstance.objects.all().aggregate(sum=Sum('quantity'))
```